# what makes a function to be continuous at a point?

Tags: calculus, continuity, intuition

We know how to judge whether a function is [continuous](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuousFunction.html) at a point or not,
 but what makes(causes) a function to be continuous at a point ?

---

I think the question is equivalent to : what makes a line to be continuous at a point?

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense to me. The function is defined in whatever way we want, and then it can either have a specific property or it doesn't. In your case, the property is continuity, but asking what makes a function continuous is like asking what makes $2+2$ equal $4$...

Comment: This seems off-topic to me. But you also make a philosophical error: it's doubtful that functions (and other mathematical objects) enter into causal relations.

Comment: What causes continuity is the definition itself.

Comment: Continuity at a point is a property. Or a function has it, or it doesn't. Do you want a explanation for the definition of continuity, some intuition on what it means, maybe some background on why it is defined as it is? We can test for whether a function is continuous or not, but it doesn't mean that continuity has a "cause". We just named a nice property that we would like our functions to have.

Comment: what you are trying to ask is this, what are necessary conditions that imply a function is continous?

Comment: A function is continuous because it satisfies the definition of continuity; no more, no less. Either you're asking something trivial, or it's not clear what you're trying to get at. Maybe elaboration upon what you're trying to ask about rather than tersely stated questions would help.

Comment: @Hurkyl : besides a function satisfies definition of continuity, are there any other conditions that imply continuty?

Answer (score 3):

A mathematical property, as ''continuity'', has not a **cause** but a **definition**. A definition can have a historical or practical origin that we can call the cause of this definition. In this case the mathematical definition of continuity capture our ''physical'' intuition of a line that we can draw with a pencil without interruptions.

Comment: you mean our ''physical'' intuition about a continuous line is the motivation to give the  math definition of continuity?

Comment: Yes, I mean just that. perhaps because my training was as a physicist.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of "continuous" at a point is:

f(x) is continuous at x= a if and only if

1) f(a) exists

2) $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists

3) $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)= f(a)$.

Since the third implies the first two, we often just state the last.